# CRS Differences ArcMap 10.5.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, openlayers, arcgis-10.5

I have 2 Shapefiles in CRS 21781. The first one "Gebiete" shows some areas within a ski resort in switzerland. It is downloaded from a WebGIS based on OpenLayers 4 in which it was generated. The second one "Lifte" shows lifts within that same ski resort. This one is exported from ArcMap as a shp, where it was generated.

When I open a new empty project within ArcMap and first add the layer "Lifte" and then the layer "Gebeiete", the layer "Gebiete" is not visualized correctly. Check out the picture and the coordinates in the bottom left corner.
[image]

When I zoom to the layer "Lifte" I get the correct coordinates. 
[image]

The really interesting thing is that according to the properties, they both are in the crs 21781 but have a slightly different name....
[image]

When I first add the layer "Gebiete" I get the correct position and then add the layer "Lifte", "Lifte" is not on the correct position. There must be a problem with the crs, although I kind of thought that if you have the same EPSG codes you are in the same crs...

Honestly I have no clue what's going on here...the prj files are also different, as the ArcMap generated shp doesn't include any EPSG codes, not like the OpenLayers generated shp.

[image]

When I open them in QGIS 2.18.15 there is no problem at all. [image]

Does anyone know where this problem comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is the same projection, just replace content of Gebiete.prj with the content of Lifte.prj.

Comment: I think ArcGIS is reading and converting the rectified grid angle parameter to xy plane rotation, but it's not needed for this Swiss CRS.

Comment: this would fix the problem of the visualization, but doesn't fix the problem that I generate two files with same crs but are not visualized correctly. 

I will rephrase my question :)